# Derivative of $f(x) = a \sum_{i=1}^x 10^{x-i}$

Tags: derivatives

Consider the following function:

$f(x) = a \sum_{i=1}^x 10^{x-i}= a (10^{x-1} + 10^{x-2} + \cdots + 10^{x-x})$

whose domain are the positive integers greater than 1.

What is its derivative function?

Despite the function being non-continuous I think it should be possible to find its derivative, but I don't know how to do it analytically.

Comment: Define "derivative".

Comment: You cannot define the derivative of a function on the integers (unless you are talking $p$-adic numbers, I suppose.) So you'll have to extend this function to all real $x$.

Comment: Useful discrete **analogues** of the derivative are $f(x+1)-f(x)$, or $f(x)-f(x-1)$, or their mean. To explore, google finite differences, or difference equations,

Comment: To put it in different words, I want to find $g'(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a differentiable function such that $g(x) = f(x)$ $\forall x = \{x \in \mathbb{N} | x > 1 \}$.

Comment: @ErnestA, what makes you think that $g(x)$ is unique? (I can think of many such functions.)

Comment: So in Ernest's comment above, $g$ would be related to $f$ in a similar way that the gamma function is related to the factorial, right?

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams I don't think $g(x)$ is unique. Does it have to be unique for the problem to have a solution?

Comment: @anorton Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me note that your question, as it stands, does not make sense. Assume we are looking for a function $g(x)$ such that:

1. $g(x)$ is differentiable
2. $g(x) = f(x)$  for all $x \in \mathbb N$.

This is not unique. Consider the following process to form another function $g^\ast (x)$, take such a $g(x)$ and for all integer $n$, consider the interval $[n + 0.4, n + 0.6]$, and just slightly change your sketch (like add a hump or something). Clearly, this new function $g^\ast(x) $ still satisfies your conditions. We can deform $g(x)$ in different ways and still maintain your properties.

If you are asking for something like $\Gamma(x)$ is to $(x-1)!$, then you still need conditions. There are many such functions which interlope the factorial function, the gamma function just has some useful properties that we like (it is log-convex). The Bohr-Mollerup theorem proves that the gamma function is the only such function satisfying these properties at the integers. That is why we use it.

For other factorial functions, see [here](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunction.html).

---

I'll assume you want to find a closed form for $f(x)$ and then take the derivative. This is far easier and probably more of what you had in mind.

$$ f(x) = a \sum_{i=1}^x 10^{x-i}$$
$$ f(x) = a \sum_{i=1}^x 10^x/10^{i}$$
$$ f(x) = a \cdot 10^x \cdot \sum_{i=1}^x 1/10^{i}$$
$$ f(x) = a \cdot 10^x \cdot \left(\frac19 - \frac{1}{9 \cdot 10^x}\right) $$
$$ f(x) = a \left( \frac{10^x}{9} - \frac19 \right) $$

(I have used the closed form for a finite geometric series in evaluating the sum.)

Finding the derivative is now simple, it is:

$$ f'(x) = \frac{10^x a \log 10}{9} $$

Comment: To further stress your first point, one could invoke families of functions such as $g_a:t\mapsto g(t)+a\sin(\pi t)$, which all coincide on the integers.